# jsoup select html tag to extract title and other tags?

Tags: android

here is my code am trying to extract the title's not title of page , and

MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl5_lblCompany 
MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl5_lblArea

```
   Elements hrefElements = htmlDocument.select("table.JSresults");
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urll).timeout(10 * 1000).get();
                    for (Element row : doc.select("td[span]")) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        String[] titlee = new String[hrefElements.size()];

                        for (int i = 0; i < hrefElements.size(); i++) {
//imgg[i] = hrefElements.get(i).getElementsByAttribute("src").after("div[class=listing-content]").attr("src");
                            titlee[i] = hrefElements.get(i).getElementsByAttribute("href").first().attr("href");
                        }
```

and my html code below

```
<div class="cssFloatRight jobPagination">
    <div class="pagesSummary cssFloatRight"><span id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsRangeAndPage1_pagesSummary">Page 1 of 1</span></div>  
    <div class="pages cssFloatRight">

                <ul>
                    <li><seek:Label ID="PageLabel" MessageID="314048" /></li>

                <li></li>

                <li><span class="audible">Current Page</span> [1]</li>

                <li></li>

                </ul>

    </div>
</div>

</div>

        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" summary="This table displays the jobs search results" class="JSresults">
            <tr>
                <th class="cssStretch10"><span id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl0_msgDate">Date</span></th>
                <th class="jobsSavedBy"><span class="access"><span id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl0_MONSMessage1">Jobs Saved by</span></span></th>
                <th class="cssStretch35"><span id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl0_msgJobTitle">Job title</span></th> 
                        <th class="cssStretch20"><span>Company</span></th>
                        <th class="cssStretch20"><span>Location</span></th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a name="19308748"></a>
                    <span id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl1_lblDate">09/09/2015</span>
                </td>
                <td>


                </td>
                        <td><a id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl1_lnkTitle" title="" href="http://xxxxxxxxxxx/GetJob.ashx?JobID=19308748&amp;JobTitle=Factory%20%2f%20Production%20Operatives&amp;rad=20&amp;rad_units=miles&amp;pp=25&amp;sort=rv.dt.di&amp;vw=b&amp;re=134&amp;setype=2&amp;tjt=factory&amp;where=oldham&amp;pg=1&amp;AVSDM=2015-09-09T07%3a12%3a00-05%3a00">Factory / Production Operatives</a></td>
                        <td><span id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl1_lblCompany">UK Recruitment</span></td>
                        <td>
                    <span id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl1_lblArea">NW-Ashton-under-Lyne</span>
                    <span id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl1_lblCity"></span>
                </td>
                    </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a name="19279943"></a>
                    <span id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl3_lblDate">08/09/2015</span>
                </td>
                <td>


                </td>
                        <td><a id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl3_lnkTitle" title="" href="http://xxxxxxxxxxx/GetJob.ashx?JobID=19279943&amp;JobTitle=Factory%20%2f%20Production%20Operatives&amp;rad=20&amp;rad_units=miles&amp;pp=25&amp;sort=rv.dt.di&amp;vw=b&amp;re=134&amp;setype=2&amp;tjt=factory&amp;where=oldham&amp;pg=1&amp;AVSDM=2015-09-09T09%3a41%3a00-05%3a00">Factory / Production Operatives</a></td>
                        <td><span id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl3_lblCompany">TipTopJob</span></td>
                        <td>
                    <span id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl3_lblArea">NW-ashton / under / lyne</span>
                    <span id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl3_lblCity"></span>
                </td>
                    </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a name="19110810"></a>
                    <span id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl5_lblDate">05/09/2015</span>
                </td>
                <td>


                </td>
                        <td><a id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl5_lnkTitle" title="" href="http://xxxxxxxxxxx/GetJob.ashx?JobID=19110810&amp;JobTitle=Factory%20Manager&amp;rad=20&amp;rad_units=miles&amp;pp=25&amp;sort=rv.dt.di&amp;vw=b&amp;re=134&amp;setype=2&amp;tjt=factory&amp;where=oldham&amp;pg=1&amp;AVSDM=2015-09-05T01%3a03%3a00-05%3a00">Factory Manager</a></td>
                        <td><span id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl5_lblCompany">CV Library</span></td>
                        <td>
                    <span id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl5_lblArea">NW-Oldham</span>
                    <span id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl5_lblCity"></span>
                </td>
                    </tr>


            <tr>
```

Comment: Please!! tell me how do i select this line atleast <td><a id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl1_lnkTitle" title="" href="http://xxxxxxxxxxx/GetJob.ashx?JobID=19308748&amp;JobTitle=Factory%20%2f%20Production%20Operatives&amp;rad=20&amp;rad_units=miles&amp;pp=25&amp;sort=rv.dt.di&amp;vw=b&amp;re=134&amp;setype=2&amp;tjt=factory&amp;where=oldham&amp;pg=1&amp;AVSDM=2015-09-09T07%3a12%3a00-05%3a00">Factory / Production Operatives</a></td>    Elements hrefElements = htmlDocument.select("table.JSresults");